# How to move the LoginForm to another place

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, html, razor

I am a little stuck, how would I go about moving the login form in MVC3 C# to a self created
layout page which is done in HTML so i can position the login form in my layout instead of clicking on the login link?. I have a box in my HTML design which I would like the LOGIN page to appear in. Is this possible. If there is anything you people would require please let me know in advance thanks. So in general terms when i run my MVC3 c# application my login form appears on the same page that appears first which is my layout page. My controller has the following code:

```
namespace TestProject.Controllers
{
    public class ViewDeveloperController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            using (var db = new GameZoneEntities5())
            {
                return View(db.tblDevelopers.ToList());
            }
        }

    }
}
```

I dont know if that will be helpful if there is anything else please ask.

Comment: We need the view code, not the controller.

Answer (score 1):

Use a Child Action for this.  A Child Action is basically just like a normal action, except that it returns a `PartialView` instead of a `View`, which you can think of as a re-usable part of page with some logic behind it.  Then, all you need to do is have your layout page render the child action, via the `RenderAction` HTML helper method.

So, you code could look something like this

```
public class AccountController
{
    public ActionResult LogOn()
    {
        return PartialView();
    }
}
```

And your `_Layout.cshtml` would just need to have the following code to render the child action in the place where you want your login control to appear.

```
@{ Html.RenderAction("LogOn", "Account" }); }
```

Your `LogOn` view razor code would just look like normal.

Once you had that working, it would be fairly easy to make some improvements, like having the `LogOn` Child Action show a `LogOut` view if the user was already logged in, or use JQuery have the LogOn form POST the results via AJAX making the UI that much nicer.

Comment: where would the partial view public class go? and what is being returned? from the return function thanks

Comment: PartialView is actually a method built into the Controller class (from which your're controller will inherit) - it does essentially the same thing as `return View();` (which is also a method of controller) but you use it when you want to return something as just a part of a page, rather than the whole page.